# Explain the "scanline pointer array" in this image object?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, image-processing

I am new to C, and this struct, representing an image, is confusing to me.  It's used in this [Graphics Gem](http://tog.acm.org/resources/GraphicsGems/gemsiv/thin_image.c).

Can someone explain the proper instantiation and use of the struct, especially with regard to the scanline pointer array?

```
typedef unsigned char Pixel;

typedef struct {
    short Hres;  /* no. pixels in x direction */
    short Vres;  /* no. pixels in y direction */
    int   Size;  /* size in bytes */
    Pixel *i;    /* pixel array */
    Pixel *p[1]; /* scanline pointer array; position (x,y) given by image->p[y][x] */
}   Image;
```

Also: is the point to avoid the multiplication implicit when indexing a 2D array?  Should it not then be `**p` which can be allocated to `Vres * sizeof(size_t)` and populated with the appropriate row pointers?

**Update**

I think I understand.  Is this example block valid?

```
int m, n, y, x; /* Vres, Hres, index variables */
Image *image;    
image = malloc(sizeof(Image) + (m - 1) * sizeof(Pixel*));
image->Hres = n;
image->Vres = m;
image->Size = m*n*sizeof(Pixel);
image->i = malloc(image->Size);

for (y=0; y<m; y++)
{
    image->p[y] = image->i + (y * n);
    for (x=0; x<n; x++)
    {
        image->p[y][x] = 0; /* or imageSource[y][x] */
    }
}
/* use image */
free(image->i);
free(image);
```

Finally, on modern computers (with lots of memory), does it make sense to use such a scanline pointer array rather than a 2D array? In this case the only difference would be the implicit pointer multiplication.

Comment: At the time Graphics Gems was written, computers had lots less memory than they do today. It might have been difficult or impossible to get an entire image worth of contiguous memory, so allocating a scanline at a time was more practical. Saving a multiply was just a side benefit.

Comment: OK, but then why have the `i` pixel array member? Just in case there *is* room?

Comment: Ah, I missed that! In that case the array does 2 things - it saves the multiply, and it allows the double bracket syntax.

Comment: Your update looks OK, except that the malloc needs `sizeof(Pixel*)` rather than `sizeof(Pixel)` and `i * n` should be `y * n * sizeof(Pixel)`.

Comment: I fixed those problems; thanks a lot!

Comment: Oops, I made a mistake - the arithmetic on the `i` pointer will already multiply by sizeof(Pixel) so you were right the first time. Sorry to jerk you around like that.

Comment: OK, I didn't understand that the `sizeof` was implicit during pointer arithmetic. Important stuff!

Comment: it is flexiable array,a feature introduced in c99,you can get flex array without dimension,but the array member must be last.

Comment: Image *image = malloc(sizeof(Image)+sizeof(image->p[0]));

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The last member, `p`, of the structure `Image` is used as a C89 *flexible array member*.

*Flexible array member* is a C99 feature and before C99, people sometimes used what was called  the *struct hack* to achieve a similar behavior with C89.

Here is how to dynamically allocate a `Image` structure object with only one array element:

```
Image *bla1, *bla2;
bla1 = malloc(sizeof *bla1);
```

and here is how to allocate a structure object with `n` array elements:

```
bla2 = malloc(sizeof *bla2 + (n - 1) * sizeof bla2->p[0]);
```

After correct initialization of the `Pixel *` pointers in the `p` array, you can access the `Pixel` values like this:

```
bla2->p[x][y]
```

Regarding the conformity of the *struct hack*, C99 Rationale says that

> the validity of this construct has always been questionable.

while a C Defect Report (DR #051) says that

> The idiom, while common, is not strictly conforming.

Comment: Shouldn't the second example be `bla2 = malloc(sizeof *bla2 + n * sizeof bla2->p[0]);` ?  (of course that actually give space for one extra element, since `sizeof *blah2` includes space for one already)

Answer (score 4):

`Pixel *p[1]` is most probably what is called a "flexible" array.

The trick is to put such arrays at the end of a `struct` and then allocate a block that is the size of the struct plus the total size of the additional array entries at the end. This relieves you from having to know the exact size of the array when defining the struct, you rather specify it at runtime:

```
Image *img = malloc(sizeof(Image) + 5 * sizeof(Pixel *));
/* img->p[5] is the last element of the array now */
```

Strictly speaking, you will be accessing the array beyond its bounds, but you make this operation safe by knowing that you have manually reserved enough additional memory past the end of the struct.